# How to get the index of css element inside 'click' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a group of images with `thumb` class. In the `click` event, I want to know which image the user clicked from the `thumbs` array of images. Basically, I want the index of (this) image in `thumbs` array.

HTML

```
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
```

Javascript

```
var thumbs = $('.thumb'); 
$('.thumb').click(function(){

      current_thumb = ??;
});
```

Comment: You should give an data- attribute and get this from the click event, or give a id_index

Comment: its not an array, so what do you mean by the index?

Comment: If you were able to give each image an ID you could just identify them using that. then on click function use "var idx = $(this).attr('id')" - though this does add work to the initial code.

Comment: @Andrew every element has an index number, they don't need to be in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
var thumbs = $('.thumb'); 
$('.thumb').click(function(){
 var current_thumb = thumbs.index(this);
 alert(current_thumb);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
<img class="thumb" src="#" />
```